$f|_{\partial B^{+}} = 0$ means $f\in W_{0}^{1,1}\left(B^{+}\right)$ for sobolev functions
The Problem: Let $B\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a unit ball ($n > 1$), $B^{+} = B\cap \{x_{n}>0\}$. Let $u\in W_{0}^{1,1}\left(B\right)$. Prove: $u\in W_{0}^{1,1}\left(B^{+}\right)$ if $u|_{\partial B^{+}} = 0$.
My Attempt: I can now prove $u\in W_{0}^{1,1}\left(\overline{B^{+}}\right)$.
My Question: I want to modify the smooth functions $\{f_n\}\stackrel{W^{1,1}}{\longrightarrow} u$ so that $\{f_n\}\in \mathcal{D}\left({B^{+}}\right)$, but I failed to control the gradient near the boundary. Can anyone give me some hints?

There is a proof of a similar result in Evans' book on PDEs. I do not remember the details.
